# HTTP Status 500-ERROR [action]: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception

Tags: java, servlets, struct

HTTP Status 500-ERROR [action]: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "[L[Ljava/lang/String;;"

in log file also i am unable to find which line is creating a problem.

please someone can help me to overcome this error.

thanks in advance..

Comment: @Nikunji Whats your JDK version ??

Comment: it is jdk 1.6 and struts 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Sun says aboutz this error:

This error is caused by bytecodes generated from old JDK 1.0.2/1.1 compilers, or from a third-party obfuscator. In the past, many of these compilers and obfuscators generated bytecode that does not conform to the Sun JRE Specification. Because the verifiers in recent Java SE releases are much strict about bad class format, the java.lang.ClassFormatError is thrown by the VM when these bad class files are loaded.

Could it be a reason that your code or some bundled jar is obfuscated?

To locate the error: implement simple servlet filter and map it to your servlets. The filter shall simply pass to chain and catch all Throwable (exception is not enough) and log stacktrace.

Comment: did you try the filter advice?

Answer (score 0):

In somewhere maybe you transform the class cause the error,you should check the code in servlet. Or you can paste you code……